How to enable the UEFI File system by programming codes when the LocateProtocol returns efi_not_found?
I met an error when coding in UEFI (LocateProtocol returns efi_not_found(according to UEFI specificiations) and I don't know why)and there is the my pascal code:
These are my codes of UEFI,it is too long to look up all,so you must bear it if you want to solve my problem.
system.pas:
unit system;
{$MODE FPC}
{$POINTERMATH ON}
interface
{$IFDEF CPU32}
const maxheap=16777216;
      maxsection=4096;
{$ELSE CPU32}
const maxheap=67108864;
      maxsection=16384;
{$ENDIF CPU32}
type
  hresult = LongInt;
  DWord = LongWord;
  Cardinal = LongWord;
  Integer = SmallInt;
  UInt64 = QWord;
  Pbyte=^byte;
  Pchar=^char;
  PWideChar=^WideChar;
  PPWideChar=^PWideChar;
  variableargument_list=^byte;
  Pword=^word;
  Pdword=^dword;
  Pqword=^qword;
  PPointer=^Pointer;
  Pboolean=^boolean;
  {$IFDEF CPU32}
  NatUint=dword;
  PNatUint=^dword;
  Natint=integer;
  PNatint=^integer;
  {$ELSE CPU32}
  NatUint=qword;
  PNatUint=^qword;
  Natint=int64;
  PNatint=^int64;
  {$ENDIF CPU32}
  TTypeKind = (tkUnknown, tkInteger, tkChar, tkEnumeration, tkFloat, tkSet,
    tkMethod, tkSString, tkLString, tkAString, tkWString, tkVariant, tkArray,
    tkRecord, tkInterface, tkClass, tkObject, tkWChar, tkBool, tkInt64, tkQWord,
    tkDynArray, tkInterfaceRaw, tkProcVar, tkUString, tkUChar, tkHelper, tkFile,
    tkClassRef, tkPointer);
  jmp_buf = packed record
    rbx, rbp, r12, r13, r14, r15, rsp, rip: QWord;
    {$IFDEF CPU64}
    rsi, rdi: QWord;
    xmm6, xmm7, xmm8, xmm9, xmm10, xmm11, xmm12, xmm13, xmm14, xmm15: record 
      m1, m2: QWord;
    end;
    mxcsr: LongWord;
    fpucw: word;
    padding: word;
    {$ENDIF CPU64}
  end;
  Pjmp_buf = ^jmp_buf;
  PExceptAddr = ^TExceptAddr;
  TExceptAddr = record 
    buf: Pjmp_buf;
    next: PExceptAddr;
    {$IFDEF CPU16}
    frametype: SmallInt;
    {$ELSE CPU16}
    frametype: LongInt;
    {$ENDIF CPU16}
  end;
  PGuid = ^TGuid;
  TGuid = packed record
    case Integer of
    1:
     (Data1: DWord;
      Data2: word;
      Data3: word;
      Data4: array [0 .. 7] of byte;
    );
    2:
     (D1: DWord;
      D2: word;
      D3: word;
      D4: array [0 .. 7] of byte;
    );
    3:
    ( { uuid fields according to RFC4122 }
      time_low: DWord; // The low field of the timestamp
      time_mid: word; // The middle field of the timestamp
      time_hi_and_version: word;
      // The high field of the timestamp multiplexed with the version number
      clock_seq_hi_and_reserved: byte;
      // The high field of the clock sequence multiplexed with the variant
      clock_seq_low: byte; // The low field of the clock sequence
      node: array [0 .. 5] of byte; // The spatially unique node identifier
    );
  end;
  systemheap=record
       heapcontent:array[1..maxheap] of byte;
       heapsection:array[1..maxsection,1..2] of natuint;
       heapcount,heaprest:natuint;
           end;
function sys_getmem(size:natuint):Pointer;compilerproc;
procedure sys_freemem(var p:pointer);compilerproc;
function sys_allocmem(size:natuint):Pointer;compilerproc;
procedure sys_reallocmem(var p:Pointer;size:natuint);compilerproc;
procedure sys_move(const source;var dest;count:natuint);compilerproc;
function getmem(size:natuint):Pointer;
procedure freemem(var p:pointer);
function allocmem(size:natuint):Pointer;
procedure reallocmem(var p:Pointer;size:natuint);
procedure move(const source;var dest;count:natuint);
function strlen(str:Pchar):natuint;
function wstrlen(str:PWideChar):natuint;
procedure strinit(var str:PChar;size:natuint);
procedure wstrinit(var str:PWideChar;Size:natuint);
procedure strset(var str:PChar;val:Pchar);
procedure wstrset(var str:PWideChar;val:Pwidechar);
function strcmp(str1,str2:Pchar):natint;
function Wstrcmp(str1,str2:PwideChar):natint;
function UIntToPChar(UInt:natuint):Pchar;
function UIntToPWChar(UInt:natuint):PWideChar;
var compheap,sysheap:systemheap;
implementation
procedure compheap_delete_item(p:pointer);
var i,j,len:natuint;
begin
 for i:=1 to compheap.heapcount do
  begin
   if(natuint(p)>=compheap.heapsection[i,1]) and (natuint(p)<=compheap.heapsection[i,2]) then break;
  end;
 if(i>compheap.heapcount) then exit;
 len:=compheap.heapsection[i,2]-compheap.heapsection[i,1];
 for j:=i+1 to compheap.heapcount do
  begin
   compheap.heapsection[j-1,1]:=compheap.heapsection[j,1]-len;
   compheap.heapsection[j-1,2]:=compheap.heapsection[j,2]-len;
  end;
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,1]:=0;
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,2]:=0; 
 dec(compheap.heapcount); inc(compheap.heaprest,len);
end;
function sys_getmem(size:natuint):Pointer;compilerproc;[public,alias:'FPC_GETMEM'];
var i,istart:natuint;
begin
 if(compheap.heapcount>=maxsection) then sys_getmem:=nil;
 if(compheap.heaprest<size) then sys_getmem:=nil;
 if(size=0) then sys_getmem:=nil;
 if(compheap.heapcount>0) then istart:=compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,2]+1 else istart:=Natuint(@compheap.heapcontent);
 inc(compheap.heapcount);
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,1]:=istart;
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,2]:=istart+size-1;
 for i:=1 to size do
  begin
   compheap.heapcontent[istart+i-1]:=0;
  end;
 dec(compheap.heaprest,size);
 sys_getmem:=Pointer(compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,1]);
end;
procedure sys_freemem(var p:pointer);compilerproc;[public,alias:'FPC_FREEMEM'];
begin
 compheap_delete_item(p); p:=nil;
end;
function sys_allocmem(size:natuint):Pointer;compilerproc;[public,alias:'FPC_ALLOCMEM'];
var i,istart:natuint;
begin
 if(compheap.heapcount>=maxsection) then sys_allocmem:=nil;
 if(compheap.heaprest<size) then sys_allocmem:=nil;
 if(size=0) then sys_allocmem:=nil;
 if(compheap.heapcount>0) then istart:=compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,2]+1 else istart:=NatUint(@compheap.heapcontent);
 inc(compheap.heapcount);
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,1]:=istart;
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,2]:=istart+size-1;
 for i:=1 to size do
  begin
   compheap.heapcontent[istart+i-1]:=0;
  end;
 dec(compheap.heaprest,size);
 sys_allocmem:=Pointer(compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,1]);
end;
procedure sys_reallocmem(var p:Pointer;size:natuint);compilerproc;[public,alias:'FPC_REALLOCMEM'];
var i,istart,len:Natuint;
    newp:Pointer;
    p1,p2:Pchar;
begin
 if(compheap.heapcount>=maxsection) then exit;
 if(compheap.heaprest<size) then exit;
 if(size=0) then exit;
 if(compheap.heapcount>0) then istart:=compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,2]+1 else istart:=Natuint(@compheap.heapcontent);
 inc(compheap.heapcount);
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,1]:=istart;
 compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,2]:=istart+size-1;
 for i:=1 to size do
  begin
   compheap.heapcontent[istart+i-1]:=0;
  end;
 dec(compheap.heaprest,size);
 newp:=Pointer(compheap.heapsection[compheap.heapcount,1]);
 for i:=1 to compheap.heapcount do
  begin
   if(NatUint(p)>=compheap.heapsection[i,1]) and (NatUint(p)<=compheap.heapsection[i,2]) then break;
  end;
 len:=NatUint(p)-compheap.heapsection[i,1];
 p1:=@p^; p2:=@newp^; 
 for i:=1 to compheap.heapsection[i,2]-compheap.heapsection[i,1]+1 do p2^:=p1^;
 compheap_delete_item(p); p:=newp+len;
end;
procedure sys_move(const source;var dest;count:natuint);compilerproc;[public,alias:'FPC_MOVE'];
var p1,p2:Pchar;
    i:natuint;
begin
 p1:=@source; p2:=@dest;
 for i:=1 to count do p2^:=p1^;
end;
procedure sysheap_delete_item(p:pointer);
var i,j,len:natuint;
begin
 for i:=1 to sysheap.heapcount do
  begin
   if(natuint(p)>=sysheap.heapsection[i,1]) and (natuint(p)<=sysheap.heapsection[i,2]) then break;
  end;
 if(i>sysheap.heapcount) then exit;
 len:=sysheap.heapsection[i,2]- sysheap.heapsection[i,1];
 for j:=i+1 to sysheap.heapcount do
  begin
    sysheap.heapsection[j-1,1]:= sysheap.heapsection[j,1]-len;
    sysheap.heapsection[j-1,2]:= sysheap.heapsection[j,2]-len;
  end;
  sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,1]:=0;
  sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,2]:=0; 
 dec(sysheap.heapcount); inc(sysheap.heaprest,len);
end;
function getmem(size:natuint):Pointer;[public,alias:'getmem'];
var i,istart:natuint;
begin
 if(sysheap.heapcount>=maxsection) then getmem:=nil;
 if(sysheap.heaprest<size) then getmem:=nil;
 if(size=0) then getmem:=nil;
 if(sysheap.heapcount>0) then istart:=sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,2]+1 else istart:=Natuint(@sysheap.heapcontent);
 inc(sysheap.heapcount);
 sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,1]:=istart;
 sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,2]:=istart+size-1;
 for i:=1 to size do
  begin
   sysheap.heapcontent[istart+i-1]:=0;
  end;
 dec(sysheap.heaprest,size);
 getmem:=Pointer(sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,1]);
end;
procedure freemem(var p:pointer);[public,alias:'freemem'];
begin
 sysheap_delete_item(p); p:=nil;
end;
function allocmem(size:natuint):Pointer;[public,alias:'allocmem'];
var i,istart:natuint;
begin
 if(sysheap.heapcount>=maxsection) then allocmem:=nil;
 if(sysheap.heaprest<size) then allocmem:=nil;
 if(size=0) then allocmem:=nil;
 if(sysheap.heapcount>0) then istart:=sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,2]+1 else istart:=NatUint(@sysheap.heapcontent);
 inc(sysheap.heapcount);
 sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,1]:=istart;
 sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,2]:=istart+size-1;
 for i:=1 to size do
  begin
   sysheap.heapcontent[istart+i-1]:=0;
  end;
 dec(sysheap.heaprest,size);
 allocmem:=Pointer(sysheap.heapsection[sysheap.heapcount,1]);
end;
procedure reallocmem(var p:Pointer;size:natuint);[public,alias:'reallocmem'];
var i,len:Natuint;
    newp:Pointer;
begin
 newp:=getmem(size);
 for i:=1 to sysheap.heapcount do
  begin
   if(NatUint(p)>=sysheap.heapsection[i,1]) and (NatUint(p)<=sysheap.heapsection[i,2]) then break;
  end;
 len:=NatUint(p)-compheap.heapsection[i,1];
 move(p^,newp^,sysheap.heapsection[i,2]-sysheap.heapsection[i,1]+1);
 sysheap_delete_item(p); p:=newp+len;
end;
procedure move(const source;var dest;count:natuint);[public,alias:'move'];
var p1,p2:Pchar;
    i:natuint;
begin
 p1:=@source; p2:=@dest;
 for i:=1 to count do p2^:=p1^;
end;
function strlen(str:Pchar):natuint;[public,alias:'strlen'];
var res:natuint;
begin
 res:=0;
 while(str^<>#0) do
  begin
   inc(str); inc(res);
  end;
 dec(str,res);
 strlen:=res;
end;
function wstrlen(str:PWideChar):natuint;[public,alias:'wstrlen'];
var res:natuint;
begin
 res:=0;
 while(str^<>#0) do
  begin
   inc(str); inc(res);
  end;
 dec(str,res);
 wstrlen:=res;
end;
function strcmp(str1,str2:Pchar):natint;[public,alias:'strcmp'];
var i:natint;
begin
 i:=0;
 while((str1+i)^=(str2+i)^) and ((str1+i)^<>#0) and ((str2+i)^<>#0) do inc(i);
 if((str1+i)^>(str2+i)^) then strcmp:=1
 else if((str1+i)^<(str2+i)^) then strcmp:=-1
 else strcmp:=0;
end;
function Wstrcmp(str1,str2:PwideChar):natint;[public,alias:'wstrcmp'];
var i:natint;
begin
 i:=0;
 while((str1+i)^=(str2+i)^) and ((str1+i)^<>#0) and ((str2+i)^<>#0) do inc(i);
 if((str1+i)^>(str2+i)^) then Wstrcmp:=1
 else if((str1+i)^<(str2+i)^) then Wstrcmp:=-1
 else Wstrcmp:=0;
end;
procedure strinit(var str:PChar;size:natuint);[public,alias:'strinit'];
begin
 str:=allocmem(sizeof(char)*(size+1));
end;
procedure wstrinit(var str:PWideChar;Size:natuint);[public,alias:'wstrinit'];
begin
 str:=allocmem(sizeof(WideChar)*(size+1));
end;
procedure strset(var str:PChar;val:Pchar);[public,alias:'strset'];
var i:natuint;
begin
 i:=0;
 while((val+i)^<>#0) do
  begin
   (str+i)^:=(val+i)^;
  end;
end;
procedure wstrset(var str:PWideChar;val:Pwidechar);[public,alias:'wstrset'];
var i:natuint;
begin
 i:=0;
 while((val+i)^<>#0) do
  begin
   (str+i)^:=(val+i)^;
  end;
end;
function UIntToPChar(UInt:natuint):Pchar;[public,alias:'uinttochar'];
const numchar:PChar='0123456789';
var i:byte;
    myint:natuint;
    mychar:PChar;
begin
 mychar:=allocmem(sizeof(Char)*21);
 i:=20; myint:=uint; (mychar+20)^:=#0;
 repeat
  begin
   (mychar+i-1)^:=(numchar+myint mod 10)^;
   myint:=myint div 10;
   dec(i);
  end;
 until (myint=0);
 UIntToPChar:=mychar+i;
end;
function UIntToPWChar(UInt:natuint):PWideChar;[public,alias:'uinttopwchar'];
const numchar:PWideChar='0123456789';
var i:byte;
    myint:natuint;
    mychar:PWideChar;
begin
 mychar:=allocmem(sizeof(WideChar)*21);
 i:=20; myint:=uint; (mychar+20)^:=#0;
 repeat
  begin
   (mychar+i-1)^:=(numchar+myint mod 10)^;
   myint:=myint div 10;
   dec(i);
  end;
 until (myint=0);
 UIntToPWChar:=mychar+i;
end;
var i:dword;
begin
 compheap.heapcount:=0; compheap.heaprest:=maxheap;
 for i:=1 to maxheap do
  begin
   compheap.heapcontent[i]:=0;
   compheap.heapsection[i,1]:=0; compheap.heapsection[i,2]:=0;
  end;
end.

uefi.pas(It is too long so I have to delete unimportant parts of it):
unit uefi;

interface

{User Defined Types}
    efi_file_info_list=record
                       file_info:^efi_file_info;
                       file_count:qword;
                       end;
{User Defined End}
const efi_load_file_protocol_guid:efi_guid=(data1:$56EC3091;data2:$954C;data3:$11D2;data4:($8E,$3F,$00,$A0,$C9,$69,$72,$3B));
function efi_file_get_list(SystemTable:Pefi_system_table):efi_file_info_list;cdecl;
    
implementation

function efi_file_get_list(SystemTable:Pefi_system_table):efi_file_info_list;cdecl;[public,alias:'EFI_FILE_GET_LIST'];
var sfspp:Pointer;
    sfsp:Pefi_simple_file_system_protocol;
    root:Pefi_file_protocol;
    filelist:efi_file_info_list;
    buf_size:natuint;
    buf:Pointer;
    status:efi_status;
begin
 status:=SystemTable^.BootServices^.LocateProtocol(@efi_simple_file_system_protocol_guid,nil,sfspp);
 filelist.file_count:=0; 
 filelist.file_info:=nil;
 if(status<>efi_success) then 
  begin
   efi_file_get_list:=filelist;
   while (True) do;
   exit(filelist);
  end;
 sfsp:=Pefi_simple_file_system_protocol(sfspp);
 sfsp^.OpenVolume(sfsp,root);
 while (True) do
  begin
   buf_size:=sizeof(efi_file_info);
   Root^.efiRead(Root,buf_size,buf);
   if(buf_size=0) then break;
   inc(filelist.file_count);
   (filelist.file_info+filelist.file_count-1)^:=Pefi_file_info(buf)^;
  end;
 Root^.Close(Root);
 efi_file_get_list:=filelist;
end;


end.

uefi_main.pas
unit uefimain;
interface

uses uefi;

function efi_main(ImageHandle:efi_handle;systemtable:Pefi_system_table):efi_status;cdecl;

implementation

function efi_main(ImageHandle:efi_handle;systemtable:Pefi_system_table):efi_status;cdecl;[public,alias:'efi_main'];
var mystr:PWideChar;
    efi_file_list:efi_file_info_list;
    i:natuint;
begin
 efi_console_set_global_colour(Systemtable,efi_bck_black,efi_lightgrey);
 efi_console_clear_screen(systemtable);
 efi_console_get_max_row_and_max_column(systemtable,false);
 efi_console_enable_mouse(systemtable);
 efi_console_enable_mouse_blink(systemtable,true,500);
 efi_file_list:=efi_file_get_list(systemtable);
 for i:=1 to efi_file_list.file_count do
  begin
   efi_console_output_string(systemtable,(efi_file_list.file_info+i-1)^.FileName);
   efi_console_output_string(systemtable,#13#10);
  end;
 efi_console_output_string(systemtable,'Hello UEFI!'+#13#10);
 efi_console_read_string(systemtable,mystr);
 efi_console_output_string(systemtable,mystr);
 while (True) do;
 efi_main:=efi_success;
end;

end.

(The Names of function is same as the UEFI API provided)
These are my shell code to build the cdrom to boot the UEFI System(It is UEFI Application in essence) and mount the virtual disk file to store the files(But it didn't work because LocateProtocol failed,why?).
build.sh
fpc -XPx86_64-w64-mingw32- -Aas -n -O4 -Si -Sc -Sg -Xd -CX -XXs -Px86_64 -Rintel -Twin64 -Cg uefimain.pas
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld --gc-sections -shared -Bsymbolic -nostdlib --oformat pei-x86-64 uefimain.o uefi.o system.o -e efi_main -o main.dll
    objcopy -I pei-x86-64 -O efi-app-x86_64 main.dll bootx64.efi
    dd if=/dev/zero of=fat.img bs=512 count=131072
    /usr/sbin/mkfs.vfat -F 32 fat.img
    mmd -i fat.img ::/EFI
    mmd -i fat.img ::/EFI/BOOT
    mcopy -i fat.img bootx64.efi ::/EFI/BOOT
    mkdir iso
    cp fat.img iso
    xorriso -as mkisofs -R -f -e fat.img -no-emul-boot -o cdimage.iso iso
    qemu-system-x86_64 -bios OVMF.fd -hda test.img -m 2048 -cdrom cdimage.iso
    rm -rf iso
    rm -rf *.ppu
    rm -rf fat.img
    rm -rf *.o

img.sh
    qemu-img create -f vmdk test.img 4G
    /usr/sbin/mkfs.vfat -F 32 test.img

These return none on the screen because the locateProtocol function meets the error.
I want an solution to solve why the locateProtocol function return an error code called efi_not_found(I should mount the disk in the UEFI system according to the My Linux Shell Code?)
(If you want to solve my problem using C or Rust,I will adopt them too.)

What is the return value from LocateProtocol?

The return value from LocateProtocol is efi_status.However,in this program the variable sfspp is NULL(nil in Pascal).

No, that's the type. What is the return value? You're only testing for whether it's successful, but the return value can tell you why the call failed.

The return value is efi_not_found,with my second thought.

OK. But if you are loading the application from the filesystem, you by definition have a SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL installed. So where is your efi_simple_file_system_protocol_guid defined?

It is defined as UEFI Specification tell me.

Where? By whom? It is not in the code you have posted.

Please look up the UEFI website for UEFI Specification 2.10,I copied the data structure and data value of UEFI Specification 2.10(EFI_SIMPLE_FILE_SYSTEM_PROTOCOL_GUID).

type efi_simple_file_system_protocol_guid:efi_guid=(data1:$964E5B22;data2:$6459;data3:$11D2;data4:($8E,$39,$00,$A0,$C9,$69,$72,$3B));
